# Percentage of objects that have survived young gen GC?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, performance

I am fine tuning my memory parameters for my java application. I am planning on reducing my eden space size to an optimum value.

I would like to know the percentage of objects(that got created in the young gen) that have survived the young gen GC cycles and have been promoted to the tenured generation. Can you please recommend a tool that can do that for me?

My assumption is that if at present, lets say my young gen size is x and the percentage of objects surviving the young gen cycles is y and if i reduce the young gen by say 5 GB to x-5 and if the percentage of objects surviving the young gen cycles is still close to y, I cn safely reduce my young gen size to x-5.

Please let me know if you have any inputs for the same.

Thanks

Comment: are u using JConsole.exe to monitor ??? Jconsole is utility in java/bin folder

Comment: yes i have used it as well but it does not tell me the objects that have been promoted to the old gen

Comment: The GC logging should contain that information ... if you know how to tease it out.

Answer (score 1):

Sizing **Eden Space**:

- you need to compute **Allocation Rate** (see [Advanced JVM Tuning](https://oracleus.activeevents.com/connect/sessionDetail.ww?SESSION_ID=7236)) to determine the size of the your Eden Space.
- also, Total **Young Generation** `-Xmn` should be from 1x to 1.5x of OldGen space occupancy after a full GC (as noted in [Java Performance](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0137142528)).

Sizing the **Survivor Spaces**:

- you need to be watching **Promotion Rate** (again see [Advanced JVM Tuning](https://oracleus.activeevents.com/connect/sessionDetail.ww?SESSION_ID=7236)) so you do not make the FullGC too frequent by decreasing the Survivor/Eden space,
- `-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution` is essential, this will show you the **Tenuring Ages**,
- `-XX:SurvivorRatio=`,  `-XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=` and `-XXMaxTenuringThreshold=` will be needed to actually tune the Survivor Sizes.
- See the [Request for documentation of -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution output](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6453675) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I like jClarity, however it is a commercial tool but I believe that they do have a trial period. There are also a number of open source projects such as https://code.google.com/p/gclogviewer/

For these gc log viewers to work, you will need some GC logs to point them at. Pass the following runes to your JVM from the command line as you start it up. The PrintTenuringDistribution is the key bit that you will need to tell you about the tenuring process.

```
-Xloggc:gc.log 
-XX:+PrintGCDetails
-XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing testing figuring out exactly this recently. I've used [jstat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/share/jstat.html) with the -gc paramterer and used a script on its output to get the numbers.

Generally the script goes through the output and sums the Eden Capacity (EC) each time there is a garbage collection on Eden. At the end subtract the initial Eden Used (EU) and add the EU at the end. The same is done for the Tenured/Old space. And then the percentege of objects that lives on to Tenured is the total Tenured Generation Space used divided by the total Eden Space used.

It requires a bit of coding, but is then easily reuseable if you need to do this type of analysis at a later time. Remember when using jstat you need a interval smaller than the time between minor garbage collections for this to be correct.